# monit: /etc/monit.conf:188: Error: syntax error 'start program = "'

Tags: monit, zimbra

```
# monit -V
This is monit version 5.1.1
Copyright (C) 2000-2010 by Tildeslash Ltd. All Rights Reserved.

# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
```

The `monit` settings inside `/etc/monit.conf`:

```sh
check system localhost
    start program = "service zimbra start"
    stop  program = "service zimbra stop"
```

What causes the syntax error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a stanza dedicated to Zimbra. Your syntax is all wrong.

Read the [configurations examples](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#CONFIGURATION-EXAMPLES) section of the Monit documentation.

You'll want something like:

```sh
check process zimbra
    with pidfile "/var/run/zimbra.pid"
    start program = "/sbin/service zimbra start"
    stop  program = "/sbin/service zimbra stop"
```

Comment: FYI, I referred to http://www.alexkuo.info/?p=280 and played a bit with identation to see if that was the culprit (which is not)

Comment: @grepmaster The information and syntax on the web page [you linked](http://www.alexkuo.info/?p=280) is also incorrect. The author even states, _"I added the following to the file to monitor the user and system CPU usage. Not sure if this will work yet."_ - It's just **bad** information. Please read the official [Monit configurations examples](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#CONFIGURATION-EXAMPLES) link that I posted in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. It seems I have to decide for myself which component of zimbra's PID that needs to be monitored.